# ASP.NET MVC Configure the another project webconfig

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I want ta change another Webconfig but I'm getting erors

What I tried is

```
string path = "E:\\username\\myprojects\\myproject\\Web.config";
Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(path);
webConfig.AppSettings.Settings.Add("DBNAME", "DEV_TEMP");
webConfig.Save();
```

This said " Web.config denied relative virtual paths"

and another I tried on webconfig

```
 <configuration>
   <appSettings>
     <add key="DBNAME" value="DEV_DEVELOPMENT"/>
   </appSettings>
```

DBNAME value change to "DEV_TEMP"

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load("E:\\username\\myprojects\\myproject\\Web.config");

doc.Element("appSettings").Element("DBNAME").Value = "DEV_TEMP";
doc.Save("Web.config");
```

and it says Null reference

Comment: Close VS before trying to edit a config file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a good reason to do this, you could use something like:

```
var addElement = doc.Element("configuration").Element("appSettings").Elements().First(x => x.Attribute("key").Value == "DBNAME");
var valueAttribute = addElement.Attribute("value");
valueAttribute.Value = "DEV_TEMP";
```

Note that you also need to get the `configuration` element, and you can get the `add` element by selecting the element where the `key` attribute matches `DBNAME` as there could be multiple `add` elements. Also `value` is the attribute of `add`, not an element itself. See the [XML Document Object Model (DOM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xml-document-object-model-dom)
 for further information.